# Metric on the dual line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold and $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on $X$ with a Hermitian metric $h$. I am struggling to understand how one induces a canonical dual metric $h^*$ on $L^*$. Now let's say $\phi^*$ be a nontrivial holomorphic section on $L^*$, so it induces a corresponding non-trivial anti holomorphic section on $L$, lets call it $\phi,$ is $\|\phi\|_h^2=\|\phi^*\|_{h^*}^2?$

**Edit:** So as far as I understand, we get a map
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(X;L)\rightarrow \Gamma(X;L^*)\\
\phi\mapsto \phi^*; \phi^*(\alpha)=h(\alpha,\phi)\\
\end{align*}
This map is complex anti-linear and we define $\langle\phi^*,\psi^*\rangle_{h^*}:=\langle\psi,\phi\rangle_{h}.$ Does this map take a holomorphic section to an anti-holomorphic section or we need to make the map complex-linear?

Comment: In local coordinates, the metric on $L$ is given by a smooth function $e^{-f}$. In those coordinates, the metric on the dual bundle is $e^f$. You can also work this out in invariant notation for higher rank bundles by using that an inner product on a vector space $V$ is an isomorphism $V \to \overline V^*$. It’s not difficult to work out how this induces a corresponding isomorphism for the dual space.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon, thanks I have added an edit, does the described map work and does what I want?